# which data type method load by @PostConstruct

Tags: spring

I followed about above topic.But i could't get clear idea about it.

My problem is when call void method with @PostConstruct it loaded.

Code here

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    System.out.println("Welcome");
}
```

But when I call List datatype method it does not load.

Code here

```
@PostConstruct
public List<User> users() {
    System.out.println("welcome");
    userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    userList.addAll(getUserService().getUsers());
    return userList;
}
```

What is the reason about this? Kindly help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed after dependency injection is done to perform any initialization. This method MUST be invoked before the class is put into service. This annotation MUST be supported on all classes that support dependency injection. The method annotated with PostConstruct MUST be invoked even if the class does not request any resources to be injected. Only one method can be annotated with this annotation. The method on which the PostConstruct annotation is applied MUST fulfill all of the following criteria - - The method MUST NOT have any parameters except in the case of EJB interceptors in which case it takes an InvocationC ontext object as defined by the EJB specification. - The return type of the method MUST be void. - The method MUST NOT throw a checked exception. - The method on which PostConstruct is applied MAY be public, protected, package private or private. - The method MUST NOT be static except for the application client. - The method MAY be final. - If the method throws an unchecked exception the class MUST NOT be put into service except in the case of EJBs where the EJB can handle exceptions and even recover from them.

Doc : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html